# Is there any need to have all pokémon from Kalos dex caught in Kalos?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have transferred a lot of pokemon from the legacy games to Pokémon X. The set includes nearly all pokémon from Kanto, Johto, Hoenn, Sinnoh and Unova.

The XY pokédex clearly distinguishes which pokémon I've caught are from Kalos (with a pentagonal symbol) and the ones that are not (with a pokéball symbol). This makes around half of my Kalos dex with pokémon not originated from Kalos.

I plan to complete the national dex in XY too.

Now, is there a necessity to have all of Kalos dex filled with Kalos-origin pokémon? Or is it just an additional functionality (like showing if you have English/Japanese/German/etc. version of the pokémon)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Pokémon X and Y, a total of five diplomas are awarded: one for capturing every Pokémon in each of the Kalos Pokédexes, one for obtaining all of those three diplomas, and one for completing the National Pokédex. **These diplomas are different if the player completed their Pokédex only with blue pentagon Pokémon**.

Source, [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Diploma).

Comment: Thanks. So... in the end, it is only a single diploma for both cases. You don't get anything extra, do you?

Comment: @SnowWolf You get an improved version of that diploma, but I don't remember if you still have the old one.

Comment: So if I were to complete the dex with mixed pokémon, I will still get a diploma. Them, would my diploma be *updated* when I catch Kalos-origin pokémon to overwrite the pokéballs with pentagon?

Comment: @SnowWolf Yes, you can always improve the diploma when you have a completed Kalos-born Pokedex.

Comment: Does the *improved* certificate it give any other benefit other than the cosmetic difference?

Comment: @SnowWolf Unfortunately, not.

Comment: That's a load off my mind. It is just that the list includes the legendary birds and I just couldn't be bothered to go hunt them again... and at free-roam this time. Thanks, answer accepted.